# About a measure defined on profinite completion of an infinite tree

Tags: measure-theory

Let $T$ be an infinite rooted tree with vertex set $V$. We will denote the root $v_0$, and if $w\in V$ is a descendant of $v\in V$, we will write $w|v$. If $w$ is an immediate descendant (child) of $v$, then we will write $w\|v$. We also define $Q(v)$ to be the number of children of $v$, and we will assume that $Q(v)$ is finite for all $v$.

A chain of descendants is a sequence of vertices $\textbf{v} = (v_n); n = 0,1,2,\ldots$ starting at the root with $v_{n+1}\|v_n$. If the vertex $v$ appears in $\textbf{v}$ we will write $\textbf{v}|v$. The set of descendant chains is the profinite completion of $T$, and we will denote it $\mathcal{T}$. We may equip $\mathcal{T}$ with a sigma-algebra (and topology) by defining for each $v\in V$ the open set $\mathcal{T}(v) = \{\textbf{v}\in \mathcal{T} : \textbf{v}|v\}$.

We then take $\mathcal{H}$ to be the sigma-algebra generated by $\{\mathcal{T}(v):v\in V\}$. We write $\textbf{a}(v) = (a_0(v), a_1(v), \ldots a_{d(v)-1}(v))$ for the ancestor chain of $v$,
$$v\|a_{d(v)-1}(v)\|\cdots \|a_1(v) \| a_0(v)$$
Because $T$ is rooted, we necessarily have $a_0(v) = v_0$. Here $d(v)$ is the generation or depth of $v$. We may then define the measure $\mu$ on $(\mathcal{T,H})$ by specifying
$$\mu(\mathcal{T}(v)) = \prod_{a\in \textbf{a}(v)}\frac{1}{Q(a)}$$

> There is a statement that says $\mu(\mathcal{T})=1$ clearly and it's not obvious to me?

Measure $\mu$ is defined on open sets of $\mathcal{T}$ and I don't understand how that leads to $\mu(\mathcal{T})=1$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from a paper I am currently working on. $\mu(T) = 1$ because $T$ is the disjoint union of $T(v)$ where $v$ is a child of the root. If there are $Q$ children then each $T(v)$ has measure $1/Q$, and additivity of the measure implies $\mu(T)=1$.